# How to perform non-integer index arithmetic in jit-compiled jax code?

Tags: python, jax

If we perform a non-integer calculation on array indices (followed by casting to int() ), it seems we still cannot use the result as a valid index in jit-compiled jax code. How can we work around this issue?

Following is a minimal example. Specific question: can the command jnp.diag_indices(d) be made to work without passing extra parameters to fun()

Run this in a Jupiter cell:

```
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit

@jit
def fun(t):
    d = jnp.sqrt(t.size**2)
    d = jnp.array(d,int)
    
    jnp.diag_indices(t.size)   # this line works
    jnp.diag_indices(d)        # this line breaks. Comment it out to see that d and t.size have the same dtype=int32 

    return t.size, d
    
fun(jnp.array([1,2]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is not the type of `d`, it is the fact that `d` is the result of a jax operation and therefore is *traced* within a JIT context. In JAX, the shapes and sizes of arrays cannot depend on traced quantities, which is why your code results in an error.

To work around this, a useful pattern is to use `np` operations rather than `jnp` operations to ensure that `d` is static and not traced:

```python
import jax.numpy as jnp
from jax import jit

@jit
def fun(t):
    d = np.sqrt(t.size**2)
    d = np.array(d, int)
    
    jnp.diag_indices(t.size)
    jnp.diag_indices(d)

    return t.size, d
    
print(fun(jnp.array([1,2])))
# (DeviceArray(2, dtype=int32), DeviceArray(2, dtype=int32))
```

For a brief background on tracing, static values, and similar topics, the [How To Think In JAX](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/thinking_in_jax.html) documentation page may be helpful.